# How do I find out with PowerShell that my workstation dropped of the domain?

Tags: domain, powershell

I use VMWare snapshots a lot and reverting to an earlier snapshot sometimes drops the computer off the domain controller. I am looking for a PowerShell script that would determine that the workstation is not longer part of a domain and only if it is not add it back to the domain. The Add-Computer part is the easy one, but finding out about the state of the domain association is more tricky. Any ideas are welcome. By the way I looked at WMI Win32_ComputerSystem calls and the Domain and Domain role properties. Would this be the right way to go?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've use `Get-WmiObject Win32_NTDomain` in the past just to get a list of domains. I've noticed the domainName is null when a workstation isn't part of a domain.